# ubuntu 16 python cannot import tensor flow after successfully installed

Tags: python, python-import, tensorflow

After installing python anaconda and then tensorflow according to tf documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux
when opening ipython and type

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

[image: error message]

Any help appriciated

Comment: It looks like you installed `tensorflow-gpu` but not `tensorflow`. Does the CPU version work? *And don't develop as root!*

Comment: I see the problem now. You install tensorflow for Python 3.5 and you are running 3.6. Use a Python 3.5 interpreter or `pip3.6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's because your `python` alias on Ubuntu isn't pointing at the same version/installation of Python for which you have actually installed Tensorflow.

Run `python -V` to see which Python version the alias actually points to and compare that with what you originally thought you installed TF for.